# Neither onCreate() nor onNewIntent() fires when opening the same URI twice

Tags: android, android-intent

I have an app with only two activities, `MainActivity` and `SecondActivity`. `MainActivity` has an `intent-filter` in order to handle a particular set of URLs for deep-linking:

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity">
    ...
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        <data android:scheme="http" android:host="example.com" android:pathPrefix="/link" />
    </intent-filter>
```

When an Intent with `ACTION_VIEW` and an uri is received, I want to redirect to `SecondActivity` depending on the full URL. Therefore, in both `onCreate()` and `onNewIntent()`, I call this method:

```
private void handleIntent(Intent intent) {
    if (Intent.ACTION_VIEW.equalsIgnoreCase(intent.getAction()) && intent.getData() != null) {
        if (intent.getData().toString().contains("/link/")) {
            startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, intent.getData(), this, SecondActivity.class));
        }
    }
}
```

I then test this code by adding a few links to an e-mail (such as `http://example.com/link1/one` and clicking on them. The problem I noticed is the following:

When I click on a link, `MainActivity.onCreate()` is correctly fired, and `SecondActivity` is called. If I then click the same (or another) link again, then all works well. **However, if I go back from `SecondActivity` to `MainActivity`, then clicking on the same link does not execute my code -- the application is brought back to the front, and nothing else.** Neither `onCreate()` nor `onNewIntent()` is called.

This would seem to be the correct behavior only if Android assumed that the Activity that declares the intent-filter is the one showing the content of the URI. However, in this case it's not, and I haven't found a way to work around it.

While this is a special case, a similar situation presents itself if the Activity shows a different Fragment depending on the URI. If I later replace that Fragment while staying in the same Activity, then clicking on the URL should redeliver the Intent so the original Fragment can be shown again -- but this does not happen.

**Is there a way to receive this intent again?** Due to the way the app is stuctured I cannot place the intent-filters on the child activities themselves (indeed, most times they are Fragments as mentioned above) nor declare any of these as `singleTop` (because they are reused elsewhere for other purposes).

FWIW, the full application code is available [here](https://gist.github.com/matiash/ae5e9454af268474bdff).